# UNPIVOT on Table in a Different Server/Database Fails with 'conflicts with the type of other columns' error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run an `UNPIVOT` statement from a stored procedure, on a table in a different database. I can run the `UNPIVOT` fine locally, but when I run it on a different database/server I get the following error.

`The type of column "XXX" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.`

Here is a slimmed down version of my `UNPIVOT`.

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
  id nvarchar(100),
  F1 nvarchar(100),
  F2 nvarchar(100),
  F3 decimal(5,0)
)

INSERT INTO temp VALUES(N'100', N'111', N'AAA', 123)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES(N'100', N'222', N'BBB', 456)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES(N'100', N'333', N'CCC', 789) 
INSERT INTO temp VALUES(N'100', N'444', N'DDD', 012)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES(N'100', N'555', N'EEE', 345)

SELECT * FROM (   SELECT
    ID,
    CAST(F1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS F1,--used in order to normalize the data
    CAST(F2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS F2,--used in order to normalize the data
    CAST(F3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS F3--used in order to normalize the data
FROM
    TEMP   ) AS T UNPIVOT(FieldValue for FieldName in (   F1, F2, F3   )) AS UNPVT
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc712/5)

I did notice that this error occurs when the table I am `UNPIVOT`ing, has `DECIMAL()` field types.

As always, any help is appreciated.

---

Update: It appears that creating a view on the remote server will allow for the `CAST` to occur properly. But why? I also tried using `cte`, but that did not work. I wanted to avoid creating views. Hopefully that is not the only solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error

> The type of column "XXX" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

is very obvious and one of the better messages.  It tells you that your UNPIVOT list contains columns of different types.  Here's an example that causes such an error:  [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85317/2)

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    CAST(F1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS F1,
    CAST(F2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS F2,
    F3  -- note F3 is a decimal column containing decimal values
  FROM
    TEMP
  ) AS T
UNPIVOT(FieldValue for FieldName in (
  F1, F2, F3  -- F3 type is different from F1/F2
  )) AS UNPVT
```

On a local query, given your query ***as-written*** in your question SQL Fiddle, it cannot possibly elicit this error since you have already CAST all the columns as NVARCHAR(MAX).

**However**, on a remote query, it appears that SQL Server fails the query at compile time. It seems to pre-validate the pivot columns prior to CAST - seemingly because it may be possible to perform the CAST locally and at a different point in the execution flow.  The workaround to this appears to be creating a VIEW that will resolve the CASTs on the remote server.

### Workaround

You can force the query to resolve remotely (tested on 2005 as the remote server as minimum) using FOR XML, which has the benefit that the values will be extracted back using `nvarchar(max)` anyway for conformity.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT n.value('ID[1]','nvarchar(max)') ID
          ,n.value('F1[1]','nvarchar(max)') F1
          ,n.value('F2[1]','nvarchar(max)') F2
          ,n.value('F3[1]','nvarchar(max)') F3
    FROM (   
        SELECT (
            SELECT
                ID,
                F1,
                F2,
                F3
            FROM
                [akltrsvrdb\sqllatin].test1.dbo.temp
            FOR XML PATH('a'), type
        ) XmlPacket
    ) x
    cross apply XmlPacket.nodes('/a') n(n)
) T UNPIVOT(FieldValue for FieldName in (   F1, F2, F3   )) AS UNPVT
```

---

[SQLKiwi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440595/sql-kiwi) found that using *sql_variant* as the CAST target makes the remote query work, as shown in the [chat transcript here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7233587#7233587).

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [id],
            CONVERT(sql_variant, [F1]) as F1,
            CONVERT(sql_variant, [F2]) as F2,
            CONVERT(sql_variant, [F3]) as F3,
            CONVERT(sql_variant, CAST([D20] as nvarchar(4000))) as F20--in case the source field is text (Make sure that 4000 is enough characters!)
        FROM
            [server].[database].[scheme].[table]
    ) as t
UNPIVOT(FieldValue for FieldName in ([F1],[F2],[F3],[D20])) as unpvt
```

Comment: Yes, I understand and agree with what you have answered. But, I have `CAST` all of the fields and the problem occurs *only* when done across databases. I tried creating a view on the remote database and referencing that view as opposed to using a sub-query and it appears to work. I wanted to avoid creating views, but it may be the only solution.

Comment: You need to provide pertinent facts, since based on all that has been described, the error is not divinable.

Comment: Understood. I just figured that maybe I was missing something across databases.

Comment: Great answers. Thanks for taking the time to test this for me. One issue that I did come across is with a `text` datatype source field and the `CONVERT(sql_variant, {text})` statement which does not work on `text` fields. So I `CAST` it first with the following statement and it worked for me; `CONVERT(sql_variant, CAST({field} as nvarchar(4000))) as D19`. As long as the source field is not greater than 4000 characters I should be good to go.