# SQL Server Transpose Data - Pivot Possibly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose, unpivot

I am stuck on finding a solution to transpose source data from a system via a metadata look-up table into a destination table. I need a method of transpose/pivot the source data into columns (which are by the various data-types). The datatypes for each column are listed in a metadata table.

Table Name: `SRC`

```
SrcID    AGE    City      Date
------------------------------------
01       32     London    01-01-2013
02       35     Lagos     02-01-2013
03       36     NY        03-01-2013
```

Table Name: `Metadata`

```
MetaID        Column_Name           Column_type
-------------------------------------------------
11            AGE                   col_integer
22            City                  col_character
33            Date                  col_date
```

Destination table:

The source data to be loaded into the destination table(as shown below):

Destination table:

```
SrcID     MetaID     col_int     col_char     col_date
---------------------------------------------------------
01        11         32             -            -    
01        22            -        London          -    
01        33            -           -          01-01-2013
02        11         35             -               - 
02        22             -       Lagos              -
02        33             -          -          02-01-2013
03        11         36             -               - 
03        22             -         NY               -
03        33             -          -          03-01-2013
```

Any help would would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample queries and STEPs given below.

```
select srcid, metaid, col_integer, col_character,col_date
from
(
select SrcId, 
CAST(AGE AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS AGE, 
CAST(City AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS City, 
CAST([Date] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Date]
from src
) as dat
unpivot
(
ColVal for Columz IN (AGE, City, [Date])
) as upiv
left join metadata as m
on upiv.Columz = m.Column_name
pivot(
max(ColVal)
for Column_type in ([col_integer], [col_character], [col_date])
) as piv1
```

---

**Sample SQL fiddle to test these queries (It work on SQLs 2008 or greater) -** 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5e38b/1

---

**Steps given below in case you want to learn -**

**Step 1 -**

Wish that we can join age column of SRC to age row of meta. So, we converts the SRC columns to rows using unpivot.

```
select * 
from
(
-- Unpivot query. You need to cast it, 
-- otherwise you get an error
select SrcId, 
CAST(AGE AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS AGE, 
CAST(City AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS City, 
CAST([Date] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Date]
from src
) as dat
unpivot
(
ColVal for Columz IN (AGE, City, [Date])
) as upiv
```

Note - Why are we casting ? Refer this - [UNPIVOT on Table in a Different Server/Database Fails with 'conflicts with the type of other columns' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827663/unpivot-on-table-in-a-different-server-database-fails-with-conflicts-with-the-t)

Output -

```
SrcId, ColVal, Columz
1,32,AGE
1,London,City
1,2013-01-01,Date
2,35,AGE
2,Lagos,City
2,2013-02-01,Date
3,36,AGE
3,NY,City
3,2013-03-01,Date
```

**STEP 2 -**

Now we are a ready to join the metadata table. We simply add the following join 
to above code -

```
left join metadata as m
on upiv.Columz = m.Column_name
```

Output -

```
SrcId,ColVal,Columz,MetaId,Column_Name,Column_Type
1,32,AGE,11,AGE,col_integer
1,London,City,22,City,col_character
1,2013-01-01,Date,33,Date,col_date
2,35,AGE,11,AGE,col_integer
2,Lagos,City,22,City,col_character
2,2013-02-01,Date,33,Date,col_date
3,36,AGE,11,AGE,col_integer
3,NY,City,22,City,col_character
3,2013-03-01,Date,33,Date,col_date
```

**STEP 3 -**

We now see that we want to convert those rows in the Column_Type column to columns as per your need. So we uses a PIVOT. We add the following code to above code

```
pivot(
max(ColVal)
for Column_type in ([col_integer], [col_character], [col_date])
) as piv1
```

Output -

```
SrcId,Columz,MetaId,Column_Name,col_integer,col_character,col_date
1,AGE,11,AGE,32,NULL,NULL
1,City,22,City,NULL,London,NULL
1,Date,33,Date,NULL,NULL,2013-01-01
2,AGE,11,AGE,35,NULL,NULL
2,City,22,City,NULL,Lagos,NULL
2,Date,33,Date,NULL,NULL,2013-02-01
3,AGE,11,AGE,36,NULL,NULL
3,City,22,City,NULL,NY,NULL
3,Date,33,Date,NULL,NULL,2013-03-01
```

**STEP 4 -**

This result has some extra columns. To remove the extra columns change first line in `STEP 1`, i.e `select *` to `select srcid, metaid, col_integer, col_character,col_date`